# Email not go to BCC address

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

i have set a BCC address like this but it does not go out

```
 Contact con1 =  new Contact();
 con1.FirstName = 'Anil';
 con1.LastName = 'Dutt';
 con1.Email = 'anil@setup.com';
 insert con1;

 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
 mail1.setTargetObjectId(con1.Id);
 mail1.setWhatId(opp.Id);
 mail1.setTemplateId('00Xd0000000PJGH');
 String[] bccEmail = new String[]{'xxxx@gmail.com'};
 mail1.setBccAddresses(bccEmail);
 Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail1 });
 delete con1;
```

Mail goes to anil@setup.com but not to xxxx@gmail.com

i tried mail1.setBccSender(true) but also not working

No error and BCC compliance is also not enabled

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Just changed your email addresses so you don't get spam!

Comment: mail1.setBccSender(true) actually works, the problem was some other

Answer (score 3):

From the table of [SingleEmailMessage Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=SingleEmailMessage):

**setBccAddresses**

> A list of blind carbon copy (BCC) addresses. The maximum allowed is 25. *This argument is allowed only when a template is not used.*

Emphasis mine.  Hope this helps.